# How to make an kiosk type application for the car?

Tags: boot, performance

How would I create an application that is the first and only thing a user sees?

I want to create an application for my car. The app will need to boot as quickly as possible and completely take over any desktops.

What OS would be best to achieve this(if any)?

What language would be best to use to do this?

**Edit 1:**

My goals for this project are to:

- Learn more about programming
- Learn about Raspberry Pi
- Produce an application that I will use

I want the app to start off small but basically be able to do anything e.g.

Firstly I'll get it playing music, then perhaps look into satellite navigation, I'm also going to hook it up to my car via OBD II.

I do have previous experience with software development, I'm a C# developer so I would be more than happy to learn C++ or Python or any other language that would suit my project.

Comment: What are your goals for the project?

Comment: My goal is to learn more about a) programming b) raspberry pi programming c) create something that I might use

Comment: What should the final product be able to do? Control music, be used for navigation or something else? Depending on your needs, it might be very different programming languages you could use to solve the task.

Comment: @Jervelund I've edited my question to reflect these comments basically this is a learning experience, it could go anywhere :)

Answer (score 1):

As I have a lot of experience with web development, I'm going to give you a very biased answer:

You can set chrome to startup in kiosk mode and display a HTML page, to get something running fast. If you want to start with music control, you can use an Apache+PHP / Node.JS server to control a mp3 player to play music in the background. [https://github.com/benkaiser/node-music-player]

Node.JS could be used for OBD2, as serial communication is possible to do. [https://github.com/EricSmekens/node-serial-obd]

Navigation is more difficult, but I suppose you could integrate google maps for navigation, given you can get the position of your car into Chrome (perhaps using a GPS dongle).

You could perhaps get better results by using C++ / Python / Java, but it really depends on your previous programming knowledge.

Comment: Your updated answer shows you have experience with Python - you could use the same solution and a Python powered webserver. (see also https://github.com/MobilityLab/TransitScreen/wiki/Raspberry-Pi)

Another answer is to do the whole application with C++ or Python, but I don't have experience with that, unfortunately. :-)